# Can I use SELECT statement for values in a list partition? Or do I need to explicitly state them?

Tags: partitioning, postgresql-10

So I have a table I would like to partition, and in creating the partitions I am trying to run a statement like this:

```sql
partition by list(apple_type)

create table foo.apples_green 
partition of foo.apples_master 
for values in(select apple_type from foo.fruits where fruit_type = 'apples' and color ='green');
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an error: ERROR: syntax at or near "select".  I don't understand if it's just not something that can be done in postgres10, or if I am totally missing some type of syntax.  Any help would be great.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtable.html), which says about partition bounds:

> and **partition_bound_spec** is:
>
> ```
> IN ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | NULL } [, ...] ) |
> FROM ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | MINVALUE | MAXVALUE } [, ...] )
> TO ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | MINVALUE | MAXVALUE } [, ...] )
> ```

Nowhere does it say "subselect"; only literal values and special keywords that substitute literal values are allowed.

Comment: Well then, thank you much, I appreciate it!